# html scroll down to div over django view

Tags: html, django

I'm kinda new to django and html and I wanted to know if its possible to scroll down a page to a div id by using a django view. (without using javascript)

In my html code I have something like:

```
<form type="POST" action="/submit_comment/">
...
</form>
```

Then in my urls I have:

```
url(r'^submit_message/$',page_views.Vep_submit_message),
```

And normally when a comment is submited, I process the form, and check for errors etc, then I render the previous page with the new information.

The problem is that it is a long page and I'd like to display the page scrolled to the comments div.

the comments div has an id, so normally by using `/submit_message/#comments` or `/submit_message#comments/`the window should get scrolled.

But it seems that django has some problems handling this:

**You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data.**

Is it possible to do something without javascript? Thanks!

Comment: Django is in server side, and server ignore everything after '#' in url

Comment: @Gocht thanks you saved me much time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution by adding the following meta

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=#comments">`